# How to create a calculator that calculates multiple expressions (more than two) with proper division

Tags: c, arrays, calculator

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){


char exp[100];
char op;
int  op1 = 0;
int  op2 = 0;
int  i = 0;


printf("Enter Expression:");
scanf("%s" , &exp);


while(*(exp+i) != '\0'){

if(i == 0)
op1 = *(exp+i++) - '0';
op = *(exp+i++) - '0';
op2 = *(exp+i++) - '0';


switch(op){

case '+': op1 = op1 + op2;
break;

case '-': opt1 = op1 - op2;
break;

case '*': opt1 = opt1 * op2;
break;

case '/': opt1 = opt1 / opt2;
break;}

printf("%d\n" , opt1);

return (1);}}
```

NOTE: This programs division doesn't work correctly.

I am trying to create a calculator that computes multiple expressions (preferably as many as the user wants) with: addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. Example: the value of the expression 6+4*3/7-9 = 5. I am trying to get it to compute in strict left to right evaluation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes. How to input multiple expressions other than two?

Comment: That's too broad of a question for Stack Overflow. "By learning C" is the only reasonable answer. As it is, your question is likely to be closed in fairly short order.

Comment: You sort of have it. Start by setting `op1= *exp - '0'` and `i=1` outside the loop. Then repeatedly read `op` and `op2` inside the loop. Finally, print `op1` after the loop ends.

Comment: @user3386109: yeah that's what I figured as well. OP may benefit from paper and pencil and drawing it as a flowchart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naive left-to-right solution is to keep on incrementing `i` (which, uh, you already seem to be doing, but with a weird constraint?). Mind the typo in `op1` vs. `opt1` -- this code will not compile! Also, use `exp[i]` to index single characters. Finally, do not use the *variable name* `exp`, as you may want to add `math.h` some day.

About the loop: I don't see why you need to test `if (i == 0)` at the start of the `while` loop. (On 2nd reading: your indentation is making it unclear and so you just may have it already ...) A proper sum is

```
digit ( [+-*/] digit)*
```

i.e., *before* the `while`, grab your `op1`. Then, inside the loop, grab the next operator and operand and update `op1`. Loop until done, print result.

That said, your main question appears to be

> This programs division doesn't work correctly.

It does -- *for integers*. Your example `6+4*3/7-9` gets calculated left-to-right as

```
6 + 4 = 10
  * 3 = 30
  / 7 = 4
  - 9 = -5
```

As you can see, `30/7 = 4`, which is the correct result for an integer division. If you want to use decimals (where `30/7=4.285714285714`), do not use integers but a `float` or `double` type for `op1` and `op2`. Since you only grab one digit at a time, nothing else needs changing in your code, *except* for the very last `printf`:

```
printf("%f\n" , opt1);
```